# Apache FTPSClient Cross OS Issue

Tags: java, apache, ftp

My Windows 7 is providing FTP service using FileZilla Server. On the other hand, a Debian client would like to access the FTP server via Apache FTPsClient. The way I construct the client is shown below:

```
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient("TLS", true);
client.setAuthValue(authValue);
client.configure(new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX));
client.connect("127.0.0.1", 990);
client.login("username", "password");
client.execPBSZ(0);
client.execPROT("P");
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

With the above client on Windows, I can successfully retrieve a list of directory in my FTP server. The same client on Debian is however failed to connect to my Windows server. May anyone give me a hand? Many Thanks^^

---

The Debian client throws the following exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:188)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:209)
```

while there is no log for the above connect event.

Comment: **You should debug the issue for the following points:** Any firewall active? FTP server correctly configured for passive mode? Can an other client connect properly? Are the ports and ip addresses correct? At what step of connecting does the problem appear? Is there a stacktrace thrown by the application?

Comment: Thanks Ferrybig. The firewall of my Windows host is off. I can successfully connect to my Windows host on my Debian using FileZilla Client. When the FileZilla Client connects to the host, I see a correct client login on the FileZilla Server console, so I believe the server is okay.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to port 990 with FileZilla? Show us a FileZilla log file for that.

Comment: Hi Martin! You mean FileZilla Client log?

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood the reference to the FileZilla in your question. But anyway, yes, are you able to connect to your server using any (GUI?) FTP client (for example the FileZilla client) from the Debian?

Comment: Sorry Ferrybig and Martin, I have made sth wrong. My Debian FileZilla client can't access Windows host via port 990, while the client on Windows  can. On my FileZilla Server, I have allowed FTP over TLS using port 990

Comment: So there must be a firewall or NAT on the way. Anyway, why do you want to use port 990? Use standard port 21 instead, if that works.

Comment: Thanks Martin! You're right!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, many thanks to Martin Prikryl.

Following setup guide, I've created a rule on Firewall allowing access on a port for normal FTP file transfer, but haven't for port 990. After creating new rule for port 990, everything works.

The setup guide for reference
http://www.howtogeek.com/140352/how-to-host-an-ftp-server-on-windows-with-filezilla/